# Simplify a jsonb request

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, jsonb

I am a newbie in request involving jsonb.

Can this one be improved? collections is a huge jsonb field and maybe one cross join is enough.

```
SELECT actions
FROM layouts
         CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(elements) AS element
         CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(element.value->'sub'->'actions') as actions
WHERE id = 124350001
  AND actions->>'id' = '1234'
  AND "deletedAt" IS NULL;
```

Here is an example of the "elements" field value:

```
{
  "sub": { "actions": [{"id":"1234", "name": "one"},{"id":"45678", name: 'two'}] }
}
```

The request should return an action, for example:

```
{"id":"1234", "name": "one"}
```

Comment: This can be improved by properly normalizing your data model.  `jsonb_path_query()` might be a way to simplify it, but without more details on how the JSON value looks like and what the result is you want this is really hard to answer.

Comment: the jsonb model can't change (it will change in another big refacto work and is not the subject of this thread). Today it's a very big json with a lot of objects and arrays, like 30mb sometimes.

Comment: How to specify with jsonb_path_query to return the action whose id='1234'?

Comment: Again: please show us some sample data and what the output should look like exactly.

Comment: I've edited the post to add sample data & result. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a JSON path query, to extract that element from the column's value:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(elements, '$.sub.actions[*] ? (@.id == "1234")') as actions
from layouts
WHERE id = 124350001
  AND "deletedAt" IS NULL;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=23e34e205998d28cbb22499213d3e6b7)

Comment: Thank you very much. The postgres doc about jsonb is as bad as if they want not us to use it.

Comment: Well, it's a reference manual, not a tutorial. I did learn the above from the manual. The syntax I have used is explained in detail [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH)